# Chapter style using chaptername and chapter number inside TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, memoir, appendices, naming

I am trying to define my own chapter style for my thesis. I am using `memoir`, and want to put the part that says e.g. "Chapter 3" or "Appendix C" inside a single TikZ figure. My code so far is the following, but naturally it doesn't work for appendices, because they will also just read e.g. "Chapter C" and not "Appendix C". I have been looking around the web and the `memoir` documentation, and I found that I might be able to use `\@chapapp`, but I got nowhere with that.. Can you help?

```
\makechapterstyle{nicechap}
{
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0cm}    % Distance from top of page to chapter headings
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1cm}     % Distance from chapter text to body
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{0cm}       % Distance between chapter number and heading

    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\huge\scshape}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\scshape\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
    \renewcommand\printchapternum
    {
        \makebox[0pt][l]
        {
            %\tikzset{external/remake next}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick]
                \node[draw, minimum height=3em] at (0,0) (chap) {\chapnamefont {\bfseries Chapter~\thechapter}};
                % other TikZ drawing stuff here..       
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should wrap the entire `\makechapterstyle{nicechap}{...}` inside a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair, and replace `Chapter` with `\@chapapp`. Why? Because when you issue `\appendix` in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) it redefines `\@chapapp` to be `\appendixname` (which expands to Appendix), in addition to some other things (including the chapter counter representation). Have you tried that? I guess I don't really know what you mean by "I got nowhere with that..."

Comment: Ah, thanks. The problem was I didn't use \makeatletter .. \makeatother. Whatever error I was getting, it didn't make sense to me. How would I make it work for whatever is in the backmatter and frontmatter too?

Also, do you wanna post an answer so I can give credits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the entire `\makechapterstyle{nicechap}{...}` inside a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair, and replace `Chapter` with `\@chapapp`:

```
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{nicechap}
{
    \setlength{\beforechapskip}{0cm}    % Distance from top of page to chapter headings
    \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1cm}     % Distance from chapter text to body
    \setlength{\midchapskip}{0cm}       % Distance between chapter number and heading

    \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\huge\scshape}
    \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
    \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\huge\scshape\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
    \renewcommand\printchapternum
    {
        \makebox[0pt][l]
        {
            %\tikzset{external/remake next}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[->, thick]
                \node[draw, minimum height=3em] at (0,0) (chap) {\chapnamefont {\bfseries\@chapapp~\thechapter}};
                % other TikZ drawing stuff here..       
            \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    }
}
\makeatother
```

Why? Because you're using an `@` symbol inside a macro definition. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764) Also, because when you issue `\appendix` in [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) it redefines `\@chapapp` to be `\appendixname` (which expands to `Appendix`), in addition to some other things (including the chapter counter representation).

The above suggestion should work regardless of where it's used (`\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` or `\backmatter`). Note that you need to issue `\appendix` before your appendices so that `\@chapapp` is updated accordingly.

Comment: Very nice, however, it doesnt work for stuff in frontmatter and backmatter. I found a suggestion from Lars Madsen [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-08/msg00287.html), saying to use `\renewcommand\printchapternonum[1]{\begin{tikzpicture} ... ##1 \end{tikzpicture}}`, but doing that I get an error saying "Argument of \@nameuse has an extra }"

Comment: @MartinLauridsen: Yes, within `\frontmatter` and `\backmatter`, `\chapter` is used in its starred-form. When I include your references `\renewcommand`, it works fine (centering the chapter name). If you're still having problems, [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/62758/edit) and add the relevant detail.

Comment: Yeah, the stuff in the reference works, but if you remove that and put the ##1 inside even simple tikz, it doesnt work for me anymore..